# How do I compute the Taylor Series for $\arctan(x)$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I've just stumbled upon Taylor Series on Wikipedia and I've been trying to obtain an expansion for $\arctan(x)$, but I can't manage to see a pattern for the $n$th derivative . Can someone come up with a solution ?

Comment: Integrate the series for $1/(1+x^2)$ (this series can be obtained from the Geometric series).

Comment: have you heard of google? http://www.mathstat.concordia.ca/faculty/rhall/mc/arctan.pdf

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: Computing the nth derivative is not the only way to get a Taylor series, see the above comments. Another nice method, but not useful here, is getting a linear differential equation for your function and applying [Frobenius method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by David Mitra, start with $$\frac {1}{1+y}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n} y^n$$ Replace now $y$ by $x^2$ to get $$\frac {1}{1+x^2}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n} x^{2n}$$ Now, integrate both sides with respect fo $x$. The lhs is $\tan ^{-1}(x)$ and the rhs what you are looking for.

Comment: And it holds for $|x|<1$ :-) (actually the OP didn't say where he wanted the Taylor series, but one can safely assume it at's $0$) +1 of course

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. I totally agree with you ! What is interesting to me is that, what I have been teached (looooong time ago), professors used to speak about Taylor at $x=0$ and McLaurin at $x=a$. Cheers.